# multiple http request handle in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i am trying to get multiple http request data, but i doesn,t get all request data. i am getting only first request data.

thanks in advance...

my function

```
async asyncCall() {
    return await this.subscription.push(forkJoin([this.http.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=15006679-5b02255bc032741ef0&q=phone wallpaper&per_page=200&min_height=200"),
            this.http.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=15006679-5b02255bc032741ef0&q=dog&per_page=200&min_height=200`"),
            this.http.get("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=15006679-5b02255bc032741ef0&q=cat&per_page=200&min_height=200`")
        ])
        .subscribe((data: any) => {

            // console.log("dtdtdt", data.map(e => console.log("e", e)))
            // console.log(data.length)
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                return this.images = data[i].hits;
            }
        }))
}
```

my html

```
  <div [ngSwitch]="galleryType">
    <div class="images" *ngSwitchCase="'pinterest'">
      <div class="one-image" *ngFor="let image of images, let i = index"  tappable (click)="presentModal(i)">
        <img src={{image.webformatURL}}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a typo (char '\`') at the end of the second and third url?.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are `return`ing in your loop (and the typo that @cabesuon mentioned).

Instead attach the hits to your `images` array:

```
this.images = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    this.images.concat(data[i].hits);
}

return this.images;
```